# Avoid recompiling Scalas script

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-script

I like the idea of using Scala as a scripting language (https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Scripts.html). However, it always takes a long time even for a simplest Hello World script to run, presumably because sbt is recompiling the script every time.

Is there a way to instruct sbt to save the compilation results, in case the script hasn't changed since the last compilation?

Comment: I think you cannot avoid recompilation fully, but you can use ammonite instead of vanilla scala REPL. Surely things you put into predef would get cached.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok Thanks, looks like ammonite is exactly what I was looking for :) Never heard of it before, will definitely give it a try!